# Javascript functional recursion (aka 'do more with less')

Tags: javascript, recursion, dynamic, navigation

I'm working on a hardware device navigation system in Javascript/Node, and having some success with a wheel-based navigation (emulates an older hardware rotary dial system).  But as I build it "top down", each navigation level with it's own navigation functions and settings, I have quickly determined after a couple of levels that this is getting way out of hand, and will not be maintainable in the future.  A working jsFiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/digitalmouse/by8w6ky9/ or https://jsfiddle.net/by8w6ky9/

If you note in the fiddle's Javascript, there is a repeating sequence of generating a new wheelnav object for a particular layer of menu options, setting various parameters and styles for that object, then 'creating' that wheel object by inserting the names of the menu items.  There is also a corresponding HTML DIV that goes along with the creation.

I'd love to use JSON or a Javascript array to contain all the menu and submenu information, then just iterate through it to build up the menu dynamically (the menu structure will change depending on user access rights), along with adding the DIV to the DOM at the same time (this later part I do know how to do).  The array would look something like:

```
menuData = {
"menu": [
  { "id": 0, "name": "DashBoard", "image":"/images/dashboard.gif", "link": "blah.html", "subMenu": [
      { "id": 10, "name": "Running", "image": null, "link": "blah2.html", "subMenu": null },
      { "id": 11, "name": "Alarms", "image": null, "link": "blah3.html", "subMenu": null },
      { "id": 12, "name": "Moisture", "image": null, "link": "blah4.html", "subMenu": [
          { "id": 20, "name": "Overview", "image": null, "link": "blah5.html", "subMenu": null },
          { "id": 21, "name": "M. Details", "image": null, "link": "blah6.html", "subMenu": null }
        ] 
      }
    ]
  }
]};
```

...and so on, but I am not confident on how best to build up some kind of generic recursion for building the navigation components - especially the `new wheelnav()` and `navigateFunction` parts in particular.  I would be grateful for any suggestions or code snippets to reduce the work involved and/or prod me in the right direction.

Comment: UPDATE:  looks like something along the lines of a Javascript 'Factory Pattern' is what I need:  a function that builds objects.  But finding lots of theory and discussion and not a lot of understandable tutorials so far...

Answer (score 0):

Well i can not give you an exact answer since i don't know how exactly you need to form up your menu but obviously you need to access the nested properties of your data structure dynamically. For a similar job i have recently implemented an Object method and i am sure it will come handy for you. Check this out.

```js
menuData = {
"menu": [
  { "id": 0, "name": "DashBoard", "image":"/images/dashboard.gif", "link": "blah.html", "subMenu": [
      { "id": 10, "name": "Running", "image": null, "link": "blah.html", "subMenu": null },
      { "id": 11, "name": "Alarms", "image": null, "link": "blah.html", "subMenu": null },
      { "id": 12, "name": "Moisture", "image": null, "link": "blah.html", "subMenu": [
          { "id": 20, "name": "Overview", "image": null, "link": "blah.html", "subMenu": null },
          { "id": 21, "name": "M. Details", "image": null, "link": "blah.html", "subMenu": null }
        ] 
      }
    ]
  },
  { "id": 1, "name": "Programs", "image":"/images/programs_on.gif", "subMenu": [
      { "id": 30, "name": "Intro", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": null },
      { "id": 31, "name": "Pg View", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": null },
      { "id": 32, "name": "Programs", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": [
          { "id": 40, "name": "Program #1", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": [
              { "id": 50, "name": "Start Time", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": null },
              { "id": 51, "name": "Station Time", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": null },
              { "id": 52, "name": "Program Setting", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": null }
            ] 
          },
          { "id": 41, "name": "Program #2", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": [
              { "id": 60, "name": "Start Time", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": null },
              { "id": 61, "name": "Station Time", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": null },
              { "id": 62, "name": "Program Setting", "image": null, "link": "programs.html", "subMenu": null }
            ] 
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]};
  

Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

document.write(menuData.getNestedValue("menu",1,"subMenu",2,"subMenu",0,"subMenu",1,"id"));
```

Since you are on Node ES6 functionalities like rest and spread operators shouldn't be a problem.